# google drive javascript quickstart application giving 400 Bad Request

Tags: javascript, google-oauth

I am trying to implement the quickstart application that has been posted [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-js) . I am doing everything as it has been instructed. On running the application i get a error of as shown in the screenshot

`[01:19:19.661] GET https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=590193668021-m0poda5f50214v9vjvlkqvsg08t0qses.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&immediate=true&proxy=oauth2relay777233220&redirect_uri=postmessage&origin=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000&response_type=token&state=1371767407%7C0.2276743408&authuser=0 [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 384ms]`

[image]

I am unable to figure out what the problem is. 
I am running the internet on a proxy setup in our college. ( Does it have any role in making it not work ?).

Please help. Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Please run your application directly on a registered domain to test your code. It won't work on localhost straighaway.

For making it work on a localhost, one has to make a subdomain as instructed in the comments.

Thanks.

Comment: The Client id in your question is different from the client id in your screenshot. Also, don't use Localhost. Instead map a test sub domain in your etc/hosts and make sure that your browser is configured to not proxy calls to that sub domain.

Comment: sorry i ran the program using many keys and the screenshot was different from the one in the question. I searched on how to make a subdomain. So should i just insert the line <b>130.0.0.1 drivetest.localhost</b> in the /etc/hosts file?

Comment: yes. then make sure that your browser is configured to not proxy  that domain and also add the callback URL on the api console

Comment: Thanks a lot! I ran the page on a registered appspot domain and it worked...It is sad that the instructions in the google developers is outdated and is very frustrating from the side of the developer if the most basic usecase can't be implemented!